# User's guide to viscosity solutions basic question

Tags: viscosity-solutions

Page 9 of the [user's guide](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1992-27-01/S0273-0979-1992-00266-5/S0273-0979-1992-00266-5.pdf) has a claim that if $u$ is twice differentiable at $\hat{x}$ and

$$
u\left(x\right)\leq u\left(\hat{x}\right)+\left\langle p,x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\left\langle X\left(x-\hat{x}\right),x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +o\left(\left|x-\hat{x}\right|^{2}\right)
$$

as $x\rightarrow\hat{x}$, then $p=Du\left(\hat{x}\right)$ and $D^2u\left(\hat{x}\right) \leq X$. I can see that this implies

$$
0\leq\left\langle p-Du\left(\hat{x}\right),x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\left\langle \left(X-D^{2}u\left(\hat{x}\right)\right)\left(x-\hat{x}\right),x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +o\left(\left|x-\hat{x}\right|^{2}\right)
$$

and that $D^2u\left(\hat{x}\right)\leq X$ whenever $p=Du\left(\hat{x}\right)$, but I do not see how to show $p=Du\left(\hat{x}\right)$.

Comment: I think I know why. If $p\neq Du\left(\hat{x}\right)$, then it is not true that for any $\left\{x_k\right\}$ in a neighborhood of $\hat{x}$ with $x_k \rightarrow \hat{x}$ the inequality $0\leq\left\langle p-Du\left(\hat{x}\right),x_{k}-\hat{x}\right\rangle$ will hold for $k\rightarrow \infty$. Can anyone verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p\neq Du(\hat x)$.
Take $a=p-Du(\hat x)$ and consider the point $x=\hat x-ta$ for $t>0$ small.
Consider your estimate
$$
0\leq\left\langle p-Du\left(\hat{x}\right),x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\left\langle \left(X-D^{2}u\left(\hat{x}\right)\right)\left(x-\hat{x}\right),x-\hat{x}\right\rangle +o\left(\left|x-\hat{x}\right|^{2}\right)
$$
for this choice of $x$.
The first term on RHS is $-t|a|^2$ (which is strictly negative for $t>0$) and the rest is $O(t^2)$.
Thus for $t$ sufficiently small the estimate fails.